How to have rootless X on Ubuntu 24 LTS?
i have read directions: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Rootless
but after a default install on my thinkpad t450, what steps are needed to have a rootless X? To avoid security issues eg.: https://lists.x.org/archives/xorg-announce/2024-October/003545.html
